# A few questions on PEP366 - Python relative Imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

I am always confused and never felt confident about relative imports in python. Here I am trying to understand what I don't understand and then seek StackOverflow's help to fix that.

**The Reason why PEP366 exists**:
Python relative imports are based on the `__name__` attribute. `__name__` is parsed to determine the relative position of the module in the package hierarchy. The `__name__` attribute for `foo.py` is always `__main__` if it is run like `python foo.py` from anywhere at all. This means there can never be a relative import statement in `foo.py` since `__main__` has no package information. By package information I mean: `__name__` is, for instance, set to `a.b.foo`. This gets parsed as package a, subpackage b and module foo.

This is the problem that gets fixed by PEP366. It included a `-m` switch and a `__package__`attribute that will be used to parse the relative position of the module in pakcae hierarchy.  One can use `-m` to run `foo` like so : `python -m foo`

Now, here is PEP366.

Questions in **bold**

> The major proposed change is the introduction of a new module level attribute, `__package__`. When it is present, relative imports will be based on this attribute rather than the module **name** attribute. **Will it ever be the case that it is not present? I know it can be `None, '', or __name__.rpartition('.')[0]` but, will it ever be that referencing `__package__` will throw me an attribute not found  error? Is it safe to say that `__package__` is always present actually?**

> As with the current `__name__` attribute, setting `__package__` will be the responsibility of the PEP 302 loader used to import a module. Loaders which use imp.new_module() to create the module object will have the new attribute set automatically to None. When the import system encounters an explicit relative import in a module without **package** set (**Just to be clear, by module here they mean `import foo` or `python -m foo` only? `python foo.py` means script and not module. Am I correct?**)(or with it set to None), it will calculate and store the correct value (name.rpartition('.')[0] for normal modules and **name** for package initialisation modules). **The language suggests that **package** gets set only if there is a relative import statement present. Is that the case? Will `__package__` never be set if there are no relative import statements?**. If `__package__` has already been set (**This means the user manually setting `__package__` in code?**) then the import system will use it in preference to recalculating the package name from the **name** and **path** attributes.

> The runpy module will explicitly set the new attribute, basing it off the name used to locate the module to be executed rather than the name used to set the module's **name** attribute. This will allow relative imports to work correctly from main modules executed with the -m switch.**What is being said here? I thought there was just one name attribute.Here they are talking about 2 different names**

> When the main module is specified by its filename (**What is meant by this statement? Is that not always the case? Can you give an example where it is not?**), then the `__package__` attribute will be set to None. To allow relative imports when the module is executed directly, boilerplate similar to the following would be needed before the first relative import statement:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = "expected.package.name"
```

> Note that this boilerplate is sufficient only if the top level package is already accessible via sys.path. Additional code that manipulates sys.path would be needed in order for direct execution to work without the top level package already being importable. (** Does this boilerplating actually happen under the hood and the user does not have to take care of this explicitly?**)

> This approach also has the same disadvantage as the use of absolute imports of sibling modules - if the script is moved to a different package or subpackage, the boilerplate will need to be updated manually. It has the advantage that this change need only be made once per file, regardless of the number of relative imports.**Please elucidate this, preferably giving an example of disadvantage and advantage that they are talking about here**

> Note that setting `__package__` to the empty string explicitly is permitted, and has the effect of disabling all relative imports from that module (since the import machinery will consider it to be a top level module in that case). This means that tools like runpy do not need to provide special case handling for top level modules when setting `__package__`.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question and make sure it is visible when formatted!

Comment: These are all trying to understand the pep366 only. Shall i split each question into a separate post? And what do you mean by 'visible when formatted'?